# iPhone 4S - Will it have a UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, udid

I know that the UDID is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Before I go crazy and update all my apps that have a [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier call, I would like to know if the iPhone 4S will report a UDID.

If it has a UDID, basically it will save me the trouble of updating my apps right away. If it doesn't have a UDID and basically terminates the app after the call for the UDID, then I will really need to update my apps right away.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every iPhone will have a UDID, it's just that Apple doesn't want developers using it to identify their users' devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely still works - we've seen a bunch of purchases logged in our system today from iPhone 4S users whose devices presented valid UDIDs. (obtained via `uniqueIdentifier`) But Apple may very well remove it in iOS 6, so it's worth beginning to explore workarounds.

Comment: Thats Ertebolle, I guess I was really just unclear about the meaning of deprecating code

Comment: Most of the time it just means that they're reserving the right to take it away eventually; they don't want a lot of apps to suddenly stop working, so they generally give a lot of advance warning. Some APIs that were actually deprecated in iOS 3 - `[UITableViewCell initWithFrame:]` for example - still work fine in iOS 5.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest changing over from `uniqueIdentifier` to [this open source library](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) (2 simple categories really).  It utilizes the device’s MAC Address along with the App Bundle Identifier to generate a unique ID in your applications that can be used as a UDID replacement.

Keep in mind that unlike the UDID this number will be different for every app.

You simply need to import the included `NSString` and `UIDevice` categories and call:

```
#import "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h"
#import "NSString+MD5Addition.h"
NSString *iosFiveUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier]
```

In order to grab the generated device identifier.

You can find it on Github here:

https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

---

Heres the code (just the .m files - check the github project for the headers):

UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.m

```
#import "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h"
#import "NSString+MD5Addition.h"

#include <sys/socket.h> // Per msqr
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

@interface UIDevice(Private)

- (NSString *) macaddress;

@end

@implementation UIDevice (IdentifierAddition)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Methods

// Return the local MAC addy
// Courtesy of FreeBSD hackers email list
// Accidentally munged during previous update. Fixed thanks to erica sadun & mlamb.
- (NSString *) macaddress{
    
    int                 mib[6];
    size_t              len;
    char                *buf;
    unsigned char       *ptr;
    struct if_msghdr    *ifm;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *sdl;
    
    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = AF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_LINK;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;
    
    if ((mib[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) {
        printf("Error: if_nametoindex error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 1\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if ((buf = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory. error!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 2");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    ifm = (struct if_msghdr *)buf;
    sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(ifm + 1);
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR(sdl);
    NSString *outstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", 
                           *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)];
    free(buf);
    
    return outstring;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods

- (NSString *) uniqueDeviceIdentifier{
    NSString *macaddress = [[UIDevice currentDevice] macaddress];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];  
    NSString *stringToHash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",macaddress,bundleIdentifier];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [stringToHash stringFromMD5];  
    return uniqueIdentifier;
}

- (NSString *) uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier{
    NSString *macaddress = [[UIDevice currentDevice] macaddress];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [macaddress stringFromMD5];    
    return uniqueIdentifier;
}

@end
```

NSString+MD5Addition.m:

```
#import "NSString+MD5Addition.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString(MD5Addition)

- (NSString *) stringFromMD5{
    
    if(self == nil || [self length] == 0)
        return nil;
    
    const char *value = [self UTF8String];
    
    unsigned char outputBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(value, strlen(value), outputBuffer);
    
    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(NSInteger count = 0; count < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; count++){
        [outputString appendFormat:@"%02x",outputBuffer[count]];
    }
    return [outputString autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: That's a cool idea, but it's too advanced for what I'm trying to do. Thanks though

Comment: 1 line shouldn't be to advanced.  This: `NSString *iosFiveUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier];` is all you need to do after you download and include the 2 category files from the github link above.

Answer (score 3):

`-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` will continue to work in iOS 5, but you should move to an alternative mechanism.

Comment: Dave, I know that the uniqueIdentifier will continue to work on current devices, but do you actually know if it will work on the iPhone 4S? Proof?

Comment: Dave, last time I checked, it wasn't a requirement for developers to know who works on the UIKit team or not. Also, last time I checked, it isn't good practice to take random people's words on things without an actual explanation. Thanks for the answer but for future responses I recommend a more detailed explanation rather than letting your reputation do the talking.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier] still works Apple has started rejecting apps that access the UDID's of devices due to security reasons,So better find another alternative to UDID.
For more on this visit this link:
 http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/

Comment: I had an app approved just yesterday which accesses the users UDID